# red editor eclipse with python interpreter incygwin

Tags: python, eclipse, cygwin, robotframework

I am already using robot framework to automate my tests using cygwin installed on windows ( i am not the admin).
Window 7
Python 3.8
I have succefully installed eclipse  red editor howevet when i tried to add the path of my cygwin python interpreter  in  eclipse red editor preferences  I failed,

it shows only the  entry Path and a "unkown type" , while it is supposed to recognize python and robot version.

I tried to double check the path, i have tested the python robot command in the cygdrive bin   and it is working.

The only thing that works in RED is when i have added an external tool config  that points to python command in cygwin bin.

But this solution is not optimal becausei could not run an individual test, while  in Red it is possible to selec and run it in the GUI.

did someone managed to make red work with python interpreter of cygwin?

Comment: can you specify `python3.8.exe ` as program ? I suspect the link `python` is not recognized as it is Cygwin specific.

Comment: the cygwin bin folder contains python3.8.exe and the symbolic link python,  i have tried all possible combination,s,  rename  ghe exe ti to python and then tries with python3  no result,   in Red editor I can only select the folder not a specific exe so i delect yhe bin which contains  python

Comment: Which RED version you are using?

Comment: RED version  0.9.5  and eclipse 4. 11

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manged to run robot  from  red gui by changing the name of the executable to python.exe